# How to pass a reference to a std::streambuf to a method expecting a std::istream&?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a unique pointer to a `streambuf` that I want to pass to a method that takes an input stream reference so I can use the bytes in the stream to instantiate an object.

How can I pass the `std::streambuf` to the object method?

```
std::unique_ptr<std::streambuf> sb = getStreamBuf();
Object(std::istream& sRef)
```

How to convert `sb` to `sRef`?

Comment: Have you looked at the [`istream` constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/istream/)?

Comment: Yes I haven't been able to figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will not be able to directly.  Since `Object` only takes a non-const lvalue reference you will need a named object to pass to it.  That would require you to have something like

```
std::unique_ptr<std::streambuf> sb = getStreamBuf();
std::istream passer{sb.get()};
Object(passer);
```

If you have C++11 or higher you could change the signature to

```
Object(std::istream&& sRef)
```

and then you could have

```
std::unique_ptr<std::streambuf> sb = getStreamBuf();
Object(sb.get());
```